# ruby twitter api :uninitialized constant Twitter::HTTPAuth (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

httpauth = Twitter::HTTPAuth.new('myusername', 'mypassword')
client = Twitter::Base.new(httpauth)
```

It is throwing :
uninitialized constant Twitter::HTTPAuth (NameError)
i have "twitter" in my gem list, i dotn understand where is the problem

Answer (score 2):

The HTTPAuth is delete on Twitter, so there are no more Twitter::HTTPAuth class in twitter gem.

You need use the oauth authentication now on twitter.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using this one. https://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth

It's really handy and does the job very well.